# Python Socket Programming - Bad file descriptor error

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a simple server, and keep getting the following error in IDLE:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 202, in accept
sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

This is my code. I've tried understanding why, and it has something to do with closing one of the sockets and then trying to use it again but I don't really get how I'm supposed to fix it. Any and all help is appreciated. :)

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
port=10101
serverSocket.bind(('',port))
serverSocket.listen(5)
while True:
        print 'Ready to serve...'
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        try:
                message = serverSocket.recv(1024)
                filename = message.split()[1]
                f = open(filename[1:])
                outputdata = f.read()
                connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n")
                for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
                        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
                connectionSocket.close()
        except IOError:
                connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found\r\n\n')
                connectionSocket.close()
                serverSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: There was a revision to socket, everything is in bytes now. Check to makesure the filename doesn't need to be converted to a string

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

As user27994550 put in his code, you want to use

```
 message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
```

to receive messages, not the server socket.

The other thing that both of your codes missed is you don't want to call

```
serverSocket.close()
```

in your except function unless you're closing the program overall. If you close the server socket, the next time you call

```
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
```

you won't be able to accept another connection. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the "message" variable data without checking if its empty.
I think this might be the problem.

Try this:

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
port=10101
serverSocket.bind(('localhost',port))
serverSocket.listen(5)
while True:
    print('Ready to server')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
                message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
                if message != "": #Checking if empty
                    filename = message.split()[1]
                    f = open(filename[1:])
                    outputdata = f.read()
                    connectionSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\n")
                    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
                        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
                    connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
            connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 File not found\r\n\n')
            connectionSocket.close()
            serverSocket.close()
```